# Spring Reactive WebClient flux passthrough

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Here is what I am trying to achieve with data streaming with a Flux.

Svc1 --flux--> Svc2 --flux--> MVC

I am able to stream data from Svc1 successfully using a Flux. My Svc1 endpoint produces application/stream+json and it looks like this:

```
{"stuff":"more stuff"}
...1 sec passes...
{"stuff":"other stuff"}
... and so on for n number
```

The problem is Svc2 passing this data through to the MVC. The WebClient is waiting for the entire result of this stream before doing anything. It does not "block" my code, but it blocks the subsequent WebClient functions.

**My desired result is that as json item 1 is streamed in, it is processed by WebClient, and sent on out in another stream to MVC**

This way as an item is created on the very back end, it will be available on the front end before the streaming is fully complete.

Here is my WebClient code I'm working with to try and sort this out, what am I doing wrong?

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(baseUrl)
          .get()
          .uri(url, uriVars)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToFlux(String.class)
          .log()
          .subscribe()
```

WebClient is getting this:

```
[{"stuff":"more stuff"}, {"stuff":"other stuff"}]
```

Help please! :)

Comment: the webclient is getting an array? if you subscribe, it will get items and then end the subscription when it has received all items.

Comment: Yes, it seems the webclient "collects" all the items into an array (which effectively blocks). For example if I add a .map() statement, it will not run until all the items have arrived. My desired behavior is that it processes each item immediately as it comes in. Know what I mean?

Comment: Dont subscribe, use map/flatmap to ”process” the subscriber is the client that initiated the call